# JAR program not allowed to open/save under MacOS Catalina ("the open file operation failed to connect to the open and save panel service")

Tags: java, macos, jar, macos-catalina

I am having the following problem:

I am using Catalina (10.15.7) on a MacBook and recently I downloaded a JAR executable file (called JKnobMan) but apparently it doesn't have access to the open and save operations, even though the program runs normally otherwise, and it even lets me export. But naturally, what I want is to be able to save my progress and open it later on.

The message I get when I click 'open' is: "The open file operation failed to connect to the open and save panel service". I don't get this message when I 'save' but the saved file contains none of the information it should have (I checked this by opening the saved file on the web version of the KnobMan program).

I tried going to the Security & Privacy settings to give this program all necessary access but for some reason the JAR file is not selectable when I browse the items.

I expect this to be an easy fix, but so far I have been unable to find a solution. Some people experience a similar problem with email services and they're usually easily solved, so this must be straightforward as well?

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Note that I'm not asking for help with THIS particular program. I assume that I would have the same issue with any other JAR executable trying to open/save in a Catalina environment. So, knowledge of said program is probably not necessary to know the solution.